# PHP - DOMDocument : Getting the id of an element

Tags: php

Ok so, how would I get the paragraph element from the id 'something' from a DOMDocument?

Here is my code

```
    <?php
      $code="<html> <p id='something'>Hi</p> </html>";
      $dom=new DOMDocument;
      $dom->loadHTML($code);
    ?>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: nevermind, $dom->getElementById(id). I should read up more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `getElementById` method, like:

```
$code="<html> <p id='something'>Hi</p> </html>";
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($code);

var_dump($dom->getElementById('something')->nodeValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is using Xpath

```
$code="<html> <p id='something'>Hi</p> </html>";
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($code);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
$p = $xpath->query('//p[@id="something"]');
// $p - element needed
echo $p->item(0)->nodeValue;
```